# Data for red-shifting

Tags: observational-astronomy, redshift, raw-data

I am looking for basic data regarding red-shifting that  comes with reliable measure of distance of the emitting star.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Red shift is usually measured for galaxies rather than individual stars. Unless a star has just gone supernova, it's usually not bright enough to be seen even w the world's most powerful telescopes at the distances where cosmological redshift comes into play. [Hubble's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law) operates over **large** distances; the expansion constant being 67.8 km/sec per megaparsec (3.3 million light years) 
[Andomeda galaxy (M31)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_Galaxy) is 2.54 million light years away, and although some individual stars are visible at that distance, the galaxy has a net **blueshift** of 0.001001 (303 km/sec) due to its [peculiar (i.e. non-Hubble) velocity.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peculiar_velocity#Cosmology)
Further out is where you start to see redshifts in excess of peculiar motion; and there you need to start using standard candles of some sort.
Cepheid variables when visible, Supernova, globular cluster brightness functions, are all used, as well as some spectral methods: [Cosmic distance ladder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_distance_ladder#Standard_candles)

Supernova measurements go the furthest out, highest redshift, but are [still a bit of a can of worms as far as interpretation goes.](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/sne_cosmology.html)